# I am having problem using scan function in C

Tags: c, scanf

Here if have used two format specifiers in scan function but it only proceeds after taking three numbers though only two numbers are stored.I don't know why is it waiting for the unnecessary 3rd number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a ,b ;
    printf("Enter values of a and b ");
    scanf(" %d %d " , &a ,&b );
    printf("a = %d b = %d" ,a ,b);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No apparent reason you are having issues, though `if (scanf ("%d %d", &a ,&b) != 2) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }` adding validation and removing unnecessary space from the format-string. would be better.

Comment: Pretty sure the trailing space means "consume whitespace until a non-whitespace is encountered, and only then return"

Comment: Incidentally: in general, you'll find that things are a lot easier if you use `getline` followed by `sscanf`. That way, you have more control over what happens when the user presses enter.

Comment: Or at least `fgets()` with an adequately sized buffer (character array), and then `sscanf()` using the buffer as the first argument. (`fgets()` instead of `getline()` eliminates having to `free()` the allocated buffer) The only downside to `fgets()` or `getline()` is that **both** values must be entered on the same line. With `scanf()` they can be separated by as many empty lines as you like.

Comment: change `scanf(" %d %d " , &a ,&b );` to `scanf("%d %d", &a ,&b );`

Comment: Try removing unnecessary spaces in scanf string.

Comment: "but it only proceeds after taking three numbers" --> No, it will proceed after any non-white space follows the 2 numbers,  Try `"123\n456\nXYZ\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it waiting for the unnecessary 3rd number.

`" %d %d "` directs `scanf()` to wait for some non-white-space after the 2 `int` to know all trailing white-spaces are consumed.

`" %d %d"` directs `scanf()` to return after the 2 `int`.

The initial space and the second one are actually redundant since `%d` reads and ignores whitespace before the number, so you can just write:

```
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
```

but you should also test that `scanf()` returns `2` indicating 2 successful conversions.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter values of a and b: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) == 2) {
        printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    } else {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't have this issue when I paste the code into this link https://c.runoob.com/compile/11

Comment: That is became the `stdin` input ends.